# insert into multiple table with procedure having IN parameter as Record

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I need to insert data into table my procedure will be called through JAVA.

So JAVA person ask me if it is possible to take a object of JAVA (which is records in out PLSQL) as input and then insert it into tables.

These are DDL for tables

```
create table gnv_sol_attributes (

so_id    varchar2(20),           

se_integration_id    varchar2(20),           

parameter_name    varchar2(100),           

action_code    varchar2(20),           

parameter_value    varchar2(255)

);



 create table

gnv_sol_serviceelement (

customer_ref    varchar2(20),           

billing_account_code    varchar2(20),           

so_id    varchar2(20),           

so_type    varchar2(5),           

se_integration_id    varchar2(20),           

se_root_integration_id    varchar2(20),           

se_parent_integration_id    varchar2(20),       

offer_id    varchar2(75),       

offer_id_old    varchar2(75),       

pricing_id    varchar2(75),       

promo_id    varchar2(20),       

action_code    varchar2(20),           

reason_id    varchar2(100),       

product_code    varchar2(40),           

product_subsc_date    date,       

product_start_date    date,           

product_modify_date    date,       

product_end_date    date,       

event_source    varchar2(40),       

sales_force_code    varchar2(20),       

line_number    varchar2(20),       

product_status    varchar2(2)

);
```

So in gnv_sol_attributes table for single so_id and  se_integration_id there are different parameter_name.

Here they explain me like in a record can we another record and then insert it (look like multidimensional collection).

Sample data for gnv_sol_serviceelemen table

```
CUSTOMER_REF,BILLING_ACCOUNT_CODE,SO_ID,SO_TYPE,SE_INTEGRATION_ID,SE_ROOT_INTEGRATION_ID,SE_PARENT_INTEGRATION_ID,OFFER_ID,OFFER_ID_OLD,PRICING_ID,PROMO_ID,ACTION_CODE,REASON_ID,PRODUCT_CODE,PRODUCT_SUBSC_DATE,PRODUCT_START_DATE,PRODUCT_MODIFY_DATE,PRODUCT_END_DATE,EVENT_SOURCE,SALES_FORCE_CODE,LINE_NUMBER,PRODUCT_STATUS

C_1,BA_1,SO_1,OT_1,SE_1,SE_1,SE_1,STDE_A8,,STDE_A8_FEE_AE,,Add,,STDE_A8,7/13/2015,7/13/2015,,,,,1,

C_1,BA_1,SO_1,OT_1,SE_2,SE_1,SE_1,STDE_A8,,STDE_MA,,Add,,STDE_MA,7/14/2015,7/14/2015,,,,,2,

C_1,BA_1,SO_1,OT_1,SE_3,SE_1,SE_1,STDE_A8,,STDE_WIFI,,Add,,STDE_WIFI,7/15/2015,7/15/2015,,,,,3,

C_1,BA_1,SO_1,OT_1,SE_4,SE_1,SE_1,STDE_A8,,STDE_BCK_M_FEE_AE,,Add,,STDE_BCK_M,7/16/2015,7/16/2015,,,,,4,

C_1,BA_1,SO_1,OT_1,SE_5,SE_1,SE_1,STDE_A8,,SBRI_1_FEE_AE,,Add,,SBRI_1,7/17/2015,7/17/2015,,,,,5,

C_1,BA_1,SO_1,OT_1,SE_6,SE_1,SE_1,STDE_A8,,SBRI_6_FEE_AE,,Add,,SBRI_4,7/18/2015,7/18/2015,,,,,6,

C_1,BA_1,SO_1,OT_1,SE_7,SE_1,SE_1,STDE_A8,,SPUN_6_FEE_AE,,Add,,SPUN_6,7/19/2015,7/19/2015,,,,,7,

C_1,BA_1,SO_1,OT_1,SE_8,SE_1,SE_7,STDE_A8,,SPUN_AV_6,,Add,,SPUN_AV_6,7/20/2015,7/20/2015,,,,,8,

C_1,BA_1,SO_1,OT_1,SE_9,SE_1,SE_7,STDE_A8,,SPUN_AF_6,,Add,,SPUN_AF_6,7/21/2015,7/21/2015,,,,,9,

C_1,BA_1,SO_1,OT_1,SE_10,SE_1,SE_7,STDE_A8,,SPUN_ARS_6,,Add,,SPUN_ARS_6,7/22/2015,7/22/2015,,,,,10,

C_1,BA_1,SO_1,OT_1,SE_11,SE_1,SE_1,STDE_A8,,SCOE_VOIP_CEIP_3_FEE_AE,,Add,,SCOE_VOIP_CEIP_3,7/23/2015,7/23/2015,,,,,11,
```

sample data for gnv_sol_attributes

```
SO_ID,SE_INTEGRATION_ID,PARAMETER_NAME,ACTION_CODE,PARAMETER_VALUE,

1,SO_1,SE_1,PCT? (Without),Add,?,

2,SO_1,SE_1,FEE PCT,Add,110,

3,SO_1,SE_1,AE PCT,Add,212,

4,SO_1,SE_1,AE+FEE PCT,Add,218,

5,SO_1,SE_1,FEE BOO,Add,YES,

6,SO_1,SE_1,AE BOO,Add,YES,

7,SO_1,SE_1,AE+FEE BOO,Add,YES,

8,SO_1,SE_1,hierarchy ID,Add,,

9,SO_1,SE_1,hierarchy subscription ID,Add,,

10,SO_1,SE_1,hierarchy parent ID,Add,,

11,SO_1,SE_1,subscription date,Add,7/31/2015,

12,SO_1,SE_1,start of charging date,Add,7/31/2015,

13,SO_1,SE_1,start of billing date,Add,7/31/2015,

14,SO_1,SE_1,PAS(Address),Add,,

15,SO_1,SE_1,Download Bandwidth,Add,20480,

16,SO_1,SE_1,upload bandwidth,Add,1024,
```

I have created this procedure and it is successfully insert a single row in both table.

```
create or replace procedure ins_svc (p_svc IN SVC_REC,            p_svc_att IN SVC_ATTR_REC)

is



begin



insert into gnv_sol_serviceelement values (p_svc.customer_ref,    p_svc.billing_account_code, p_svc.so_id, p_svc.so_type

                                       ,p_svc.se_integration_id, p_svc.se_root_integration_id, p_svc.se_parent_integration_id

                                       ,p_svc.offer_id, p_svc.offer_id_old, p_svc.pricing_id, p_svc.promo_id, p_svc.action_code

                                       ,p_svc.reason_id, p_svc.product_code, p_svc.product_subsc_date, p_svc.product_start_date

                                       ,p_svc.product_modify_date, p_svc.product_end_date, p_svc.event_source

                                       ,p_svc.sales_force_code, p_svc.line_number, p_svc.product_status);



insert into GNV_SOL_ATTRIBUTES values (p_svc_att.so_id, p_svc_att.se_integration_id, p_svc_att.parameter_name

                                   ,p_svc_att.action_code, p_svc_att.parameter_value);



exception

 when others then

 dbms_output.put_line('error code '||' '||sqlcode||' '||'Error reason'||sqlerrm);

end;
```

Now that JAVA person asking me if there is any way in which i insert a single row in the gnv_sol_serviceelemen table

and multiple rows in the gnv_sol_attributes because in attribute table there are different parameter value for same so_id and SE_INTEGRATION_ID.

This is where i got stuck.

If someone has a wayout.

DATABASE VERSION :--

Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Nobody here is going to wade through pages of code/data.

Comment: great answer! expected from stackoverflow